# Exit Sub equivalent in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c

I'm pretty much new to Objective C but I've had some experience in Visual Basic.  What's the equivalent of the Exit Sub statement to stop executing code if conditions aren't met?  I'm talking along the lines of

```
If Some.Condition.Is.Not.Met Then
    Exit Sub //Please don't execute any more code in this method
```

Is this the correct way to make it work?

```
-(BOOL)methodThatQuitsOut {
    [SomeCode GoesHere];
    Other.code = Goes.here;
    if (condition != present) {
        return NO;
    }
    Does this code continue to run?;
}
```

Comment: Might be wise to flip through a C tutorial...

http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial.html#ctutorial

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*returning* from a function does just that; it returns, and control is passed back to the call-e.  So no, the code below the return will not execute.

I would note that this would have taken about 30 seconds to test yourself.

Comment: I wasn't at my desk when typing this =)  I was at work, thinking about what code I was going to write later.  Thanks for the answer