# Exit a function in case condition is not satisfied

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

What is the best way of writing code to exit a function in case condition is not satisfied?

e.g I have a function

```
-(IBAction) moreDetails
{  
if (condition)  
//condition not satisfied...exit function  
else  
continue with the function 
}
```

Can i simply write return ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Exit Sub equivalent in Objective C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1752106/exit-sub-equivalent-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes.  "return" returns immediately from the current method/function.   If the function/method returns a value then you need to provide a return value: "return NO, return 3, return @"string", and so on.

I generally prefer this structure:

```
void f()
{
    if ( ! conditionCheck )
        return;
    // long code block
}
```

to this:

```
void f()
{
    if ( conditionCheck )
    {
        // long code block
    }
}
```

because fewer lines are indented

Comment: Is there something called exit() as well ?

Comment: now in Swift there is even better way to do this style of code via use of Guard !

Answer (score 5):

Yes - you should use return. Because your method returns void, no need for anything else. I'd write more, but there's not much else to it :)